# Monitor bandwidth consumption of a single website

Tags: .net, performance, networking, bandwidth

I am testing a website. I want to measure the bandwidth consumption of the single website.

Is there any way in which I could measure the bandwidth consumed on my computer by only one of web application running in the browser?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be .net?

Comment: umm, what can I do if it is not .net?

Answer (score 0):

Single URL, one browser scenario:

Open Chrome, press F12, choose "Audits" and then run the audit with "reload the page" option.

After the page has reloaded choose the "Network" tab and you can see the consumed bandwidth in the status bar.